# Using will_paginate with array routing issue

Tags: ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-5, will-paginate

My project is currently configured to only have one view, `import.html`, that allows the user to upload and view contents of a CSV file (after uploading).

Here is the controller class import method:

```
class UploadController < ApplicationController
  require "CSV"
  require 'will_paginate/array'
  def import
    return if params[:file] == nil
    file = params[:file]
    @table = []
    rowi = 0

    CSV.foreach(file.path) do |row|
      if rowi == 0 #and headers (for later)
        @headers = row
      else
        @table << row.join("~")
      end
      rowi = rowi + 1
    end

    @table = @table.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 20)
    session
  end
end
```

Here is the view:

```
<h1>Upload#import</h1>

<h4>UPLOAD A CSV FILE:</h4>

<%= form_tag({:action => "import"}, multipart: true) do %>
  <%= file_field_tag :file %>
  <%= submit_tag( "Import" ) %>
<% end %>

<% if @headers and @table %>
  <h1>RESULTS</h1>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <% @headers.each do |column| %>
          <td><%= column  %></td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% @table.each do |row| %>
        <tr>
          <% row.split("~").each do |cell| %>
            <td><%= cell %></td>
          <% end %>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <%= will_paginate @table, inner_window: 1, outer_window: 0%>
<% end %>
```

Here are the routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'upload#import'
  post "/" => "upload#import"
end
```

When interacting with my table to go to a different page, my routes have no specified instruction for:

> GET "/?page=(pagenumber)"

I don't know what to tell it to do in order for the correct page to show.

It just defaults to redirecting to the `import_page` which clears all the data that has been imported. How should I fix this?

Comment: You should really have separate routes for the `post` request to upload and save the file, and displaying the contents in a `get` request. Basically, you'd split the code saving the file into a `post` action, and the table generation into the `get`. Then the `get` page's form would hit the `post` action, which would redirect back to the `get` endpoint if successful.

Comment: The table generation isn't really delegated to an action. Can you comment on what it would look like in my routes?

Do I need to add another view to handle the paginated result?

Comment: I've added an answer covering the basic structure for creating and displaying a resource. Let me know how it helps!

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, you'll likely want to use a [singular resource](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources) for this.

So you'd need the following:

In `routes.rb`:

```
resource :uploader, only: [:show, :create]
```

(N.B. this is a different use case to the more commonly-seen `resources` *plural*.)

This will give you the following routes:

```
POST    /upload uploads#create  # create the new upload
GET     /upload uploads#show    # display the one and only upload resource
```

In your controller:

```
class UploadController < ApplicationController
  require "csv"
  require 'will_paginate/array'

  def create
    return if params[:file] == nil
    file = params[:file]
    @table = []
    rowi = 0

    CSV.foreach(file.path) do |row|
      if rowi == 0 #and headers (for later)
        @headers = row
      else
        @table << row.join("~")
      end
      rowi = rowi + 1
    end

    # save the file to the db
    # redirect to upload_path
  end

  def show   
    # Find the relevant table 
    @table = Table.last.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 20)
  end
end
```

*Then* you'll want to rework the form in your view to use `@table`, something like:

```
...
<%= form_for @table, multipart: true) do %>
  <%= f.file_field :file %>
  <%= f.submit  "Import" %>
<% end %>
...
```

This is a very basic summary of how your project should work. The crux of it is using the correct, separate actions to create and show the table.

You'll likely want to look at using [strong params](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) and other Rails conventions.

Finally, if it helps, have a look at a generated Rails controller (i.e. `rails generate controller my_example_controller`) - this will have the `create` and `show` actions pre-built, and you can look to merge your code into something similar.

Hope this helps - give me a shout if you've any questions.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using a database? Typically the csv files I would like to upload have tens of thousands of rows. I need the file contents to be stored in a variable.

Can you also explain the meaning of the line @table = Table.last. ....

Comment: In short this doesn't really fix my issue. I just want to be able to display all of the pages of the paginated **array**. Editing my app to use a single resource did all but made it work.

Comment: It's definitely possible, but you'd likely need to use Javascript and / or  [Ajax](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) to handle uploading the file and rendering it on the page. It's likely it would be very memory intensive to store such a large file in this manner. Is there a reason you're averse to storing data in the db? Have you got a little more info on the data format you could add to the question to help with this?

Comment: I'm averse because there can sometimes be millions of rows in the csv and inserting them into a table would be time consuming.
 There is no need to store the files in a database. The purpose for uploading the information would be for updating an external database using an API. I just want to be able to provide a small UI to help the user feel in control with using the API.

Comment: OK cool - I think using Ajax will do what you're after then. You could use a similar format to the answer, only render the data in JSON format in the POST action, and display it on success.